Quarto wont render PDF, even though object exists?
I have a problem rendering my code from R into quarto PDF format. The following message keep popping up. I checked if the object exists, exists() returns as TRUE. How can I fix this? Help appreciated.
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tinytex)

Heart_data %>%
  select(disease_type, height, weight, bmi, smoking_status, 
         diabetes, hypertension, hyperlip, afib, prior_pci, pad, 
         renal, home_status, home_situation, work_status, education) %>% 
  filter(disease_type==2)
```

==> quarto preview quatro.lol.qmd --to pdf --no-watch-inputs --no-browse



processing file: quatro.lol.qmd
  |....                                               |   7% [unnamed-chunk-1] 


Quitting from lines 19-31 [unnamed-chunk-1] (quatro.lol.qmd)
Error:
! object 'Heart_data' not found
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% filter(disease_type == 2)
 3. dplyr::select(...)
                                                                                                             
Execution halted 

Tried finding object, with exists() which returns as TRUE. CAnt seem to find the problem

Welcome to SO, Large Simpsons! (1) [code block]s, please; I edited it now, How a question reasons (formatting with code/data) can make a huge difference, even if seemingly "just aesthetics". (2) We cannot test/debug/troubleshoot what we don't have, it would really help to have a minimal and reproducible example, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

(3) Rmd and Qmd documents are rendered in a new R environment/process, so all objects in your global environment are not seen within the document. Please read about parameterized reports, where you need to add a params: section to your Qmd yaml header, and pass params=list(...) to your call to render(..) call.

@r2evans Im not quite sure what you mean with params=list(...) ?

Read the link I sent about parameterized reports.

@r2evans sorry I did read it but i dont understand how declaring parameters would make the object/data "heart_data" be seen within the document. When I excute the code above it is visble in the viewer but not when I try to render the code to a PDF-format?

I don't know how to say it better. When a document is rendered, it is using an external program named quarto. That program then looks at your .Qmd file and based on the languages for each code block, it starts up a NEW process. So you have a new R process. Do you expect that a new R process will know to reach out to every other R process observed on your system to find out what objects it might need and import them to its own R environment? (The answer is: it does not.) So ... new environment. That what you see on your console with ls() is not available within your Qmd file.

You need to define a params: section in your Qmd yaml header, with named objects you need to pass from the calling environment (your console) so that the document has all that it needs to render your tables/plots/whatever. If you are relying on RStudio to knit the document for you, you may need to say "Knit with parameters" and identify what they are. If you are using the rmarkdown::render function to render it yourself, then you need to add an argument such as rmarkdown::render("file.Qmd", ..., params=list(mydata=heart_data)) or whatever you defined in your yaml header.

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html is another reference, which is still appropriate even though it's talking .Rmd file instead of .Qmd.

In YAML header I put in
params: data-path: "heart-data"
Heart-data, is the data saved and used.
And then inserted R executable cell where the following code was put in.
my_data1 <- read.csv(params$data_path)
I could then render my PDF after adjusting the variables in other places in the document.
